# Short way to pass zero-arity lambda function in OCaml

Tags: ocaml

Is there any short way to pass zero-arity function to another function. For now I do it like this:

```
let f a b c = ...;;
a (fun () -> f a b c)
```

Is there any syntactic sugar for the second line?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

How about:

```
lazy (f a b c)
```

To "apply", use `Lazy.force`, as in:

```
# let l = lazy (2+2) ;;
val l : int lazy_t = <lazy>
# Lazy.force l ;;
- : int = 4
```

The meaning is not exactly the same as `(fun () -> ...)` and `... ()` and it's not really shorter. Perhaps if you really need to have a convenient syntax for either `lazy` or `fun () ->` you should use a camlp{4,5} extension to that purpose.

Answer (score 6):

If `f` were defined as `f a b c () = ...`, you could just do `a (f a b c)`, but other than that no, there's no shorter way.

If you want to you can define the function `const` like this:

```
let const x _ = x
```

And then use it like this:

```
a (const (f a b c))
```

But that's not really much shorter (or clearer) than using `fun`. Also it evaluates `f a b c` immediately, which is probably not what you want anyway.

PS: The pedant in me needs to point out that `(fun () -> ...)` is a unary function and there are no zero-arity functions in ocaml.

Comment: The problem with `const` is that `(fun () -> ...)` is usually meant to delay the evaluation of the code, which the `const` function, due to OCaml strict evaluation, cannot do.

Comment: @gasche: Good point, about the delayed evaluation. And yes, I was accidentally writing SML, fixed that.

Comment: Thanks, I think I will stay with my current fun () -> ...` approach